# App script time trigger not executing my script at all

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two functions that are responsible for starting and stopping the execution of my script from UI.

```
function runScript() {
  stopScript();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("start").timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
}
```

and

```
function stopScript() {
  let triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}
```

They both are triggered by the UI for which I'm using this piece of code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  let sheetUi = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  sheetUi.createMenu('Menu')
  .addItem('Run', 'runScript')
  .addItem('Stop', 'stopScript')
  .addToUi();
}
```

They work as expected: `stopScript()` remove the old time trigger and `runScript()` create a new one.

Once I run the function `runScript()` a new time trigger is created and I can see it in my dashboard. However, the time trigger never executes the script. For example, for the past 2 days, the time trigger which was set to execute the script every hour didn't execute it even once. I don't understand why this is happening.

The script can be used from any Google Sheet. I tried any solution I found on the internet and here but it keeps not running. I'm out of options.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Your trigger is expected to execute every hour a function called `function start()`. Do you have such a function and if yes - what is its content?

Comment: Yes, I have a function `start()` which is working correctly. Unfortunately, I can't share many details due to NDA. I should probably mention that I don't receive any errors either.

Edit: `start` is my entry function, but I don't think that's a problem. The time trigger doesn't fire the function at all

Comment: If yo go to `https://script.google.com/home/triggers`, select the trigger of interest and click on the three vertical dots on its right side - you can see "Executions" and "Failed Executions". If you click on "Failed Executions", you can see the list of all failed executions and clicking on the word "Failed" will show you the related "Stackdriver logs" containing the error message / exception.

Comment: I already check that several times and it's always empty. There aren't any errors. The time trigger is created and it should at least run at the appropriate time but it doesn't. Both parameters `Last run` & `Error rate` stays empty for my trigger at `https://script.google.com/home/triggers` for the past 2 days

Comment: So before your trigger executed, but now not anymore? And you have not modified anything since then? What about sharing settings? Who owns the spreadsheet, script and trigger? Sounds like a permission issue. If you can provide a dummy sheet and after sensitive information - I can have a look. Otherwise  provide at least the contents of the function start() (after removing sensitive information).

Comment: Any change that you have two functions named start?

Comment: No, the trigger is created but never executed. I am the owner of the spreadsheet, the script and the trigger. I made a few tests. If I create the trigger manually from UI it works both for `everyMinute` and `everyHour`. It seems that when the trigger is created programmatically it doesn't work. From here `https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable` it is said `Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run` - I'm not sure I understand the 1st part. How we are supposed to run the trigger? I mean it's created but it never runs.

Comment: No @Cooper it's only one

Comment: `Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run` refers to e.g. `onEdit` trigger - they do not fire on non-human edits. This is not related to your case. I reproduced your situation - created a trigger with `function runScript()` and for me it works perferctly. This is why I can only assume that the problem is either a permission issue or the content of `funciton start()`

Comment: The script was shared with 2 more people, but I removed them. I also removed everything from the script except `runScript `, `stopScript `. For `start` function I removed only its content. The time trigger still doesn't execute when it's set programmatically. My script is connected to **Google Cloud Platform** and I noticed that there is **Cloud Scheduler API** (not enabled) which also requires a billing account. Can the problem be from GCP? I really can't find any other permission issues.

Comment: Another question: Do you happen to have changed from v7 to v8 around the same time when your trigger stopped running?

Comment: No, from the beginning the script is using v8. Just to clarify: the trigger is always created, but it's running only when is created from the UI and not the code. I thought that once the trigger is created programmatically it should also run, but it doesn't.

Comment: It does for me, but it is hard to reproduce your issue without all the information. Maybe you can try to create a new spreadsheet with a new script and trigger and see if this solves the issue?

Comment: I narrowed down the problem to the UI. Basically, I don't have anything else in the script (no APIs) except an empty `start` function and the three functions above (I included `onOpen`). I've tested every single possible case... Do you think I'm missing something in onOpen?

Comment: your `onOpen` function is correct and works for me - just as the rest of the code you provided. Mindhowever that `let` is only supported in `v8`, not `v7`. You can see if changing `let` to `var` solves the issue. Otherwise, try to create a new spreadsheet and attach the script to it - maybe this will fix the problem. Be aware that you ahve to un the script manually once in order to trigger authorization flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 2 weeks in testing and reaching even to G Suite Support (who didn't manage to help either), I found the problem.

Every part of my script is correct and it's working. The problem comes when you need to test a time-trigger or even an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) in general for your add-on (`Test as add-on` option from the script editor) - it's impossible and it will never work because that's the way Google created it. From [Test an editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons):

> Installable triggers aren't supported when testing. Functionality that depends on `installable triggers is not testable`.

So how you should test your time-triggers then?

In my case when I was testing the script through the editor the time-trigger was created and it was running periodically (every 1h). And that's the answer. If your time-trigger (or installable trigger in general) is running that way it means that it's working and it will work on a production as well.

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out this morning till seeing this commnet